# Accessing condition flag in IA32

Tags: flags, x86

Is there any way where I could access the value of a condition flag, such as the zero flag, and move that value into a register? Something like this:

```
cmpl %eax,%edx
movl ZF, %eax
```

Thanks,
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after surfing around on the web, it is possible to do somewhat similar:

Let res be the resulting value of all condition flags (Zero Flag (ZF), Carry Flag (CF), Sign Flag (SF), Overflow Flag (OF)) after the operation cmpl %eax,&edx. (Which performs %edx - %eax and throws away the result)

```
sete D  //Sets D to ZF                -> %eax == %edx
setne D //Sets D to ~ZF               -> %eax != %edx
setg D  //Sets D to ~(SF ^ OF) & ~ZF  -> %edx > %eax
setge D //Sets D to ~(SF ^ OF)        -> %edx >= %eax
setl D  //Sets D to SF ^ OF           -> %edx < %eax
setle D //Sets D to (SF ^ OF) | ZF    -> %edx <= %eax
```